# Вылавливание цены из переменной

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Приветствую всех вошедших

Собственно на прег-реплейс простые выражения уже не вызывают паники, но что то не могу справиться с вылавливанием цены из текста:

```
$price = 'Цена данного товара равна 355,55 рублей';
```

т.е. ищем цифры+(запятая или точка)+цифры. Вопрос прост, может кто подсказать что прописать в preg_replace, что бы выловить нужное выражение?

p.s. даже как то спрашивать стыдно, вроде всего 1 команда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение довольно простое:

```
$price = 'Цена данного товара равна 355,55 рублей';     
preg_match_all('#\d+[,.]\d+#', $price, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/00OxN5)

Comment: Оно самое, теперь понятно как делать ', или .' . Спасибо!

Comment: Символ точки в квадратных скобках можно не экранировать.

В этом контексте она воспринимается не как класс, а как простой символ

Comment: @Johny Точно!